# How to add a custom Search Kit Task in a CiviCRM Extension

Tags: searchkit

I am trying to write an Extension which defines and adds a new Search Kit Task to the system.

I have implemented hook_civicrm_searchKitTasks() and created a new Angular module (using Civix) as described in https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_searchKitTasks/.  The new Task appears in the Action list when building a new Search, but if I try to make it do anything by adding some HTML or JS it doesn't work.  I appear not to be adding all the right items, or putting them in the wrong place, because Angular throws JS errors saying it can't find something it's looking for, e.g. "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null ".

Can anyone point me at some more detailed guidance, or a working Extension that adds a Task so I can see how it is put together?

With thanks, Tony

Comment: Depends what you're trying to do, but you don't always need to create an Angular module - see the apiBatch functionality.

Comment: Thanks Aidan.  As far as I can see from the documentation, apiBatch provides operations on one results row at a time. I am trying to write a task that will handle all the search results in one go (by passing an array of Ids back to an API on the server).  I have now got a skeleton sort of working, by cribbing from the core crmSearchTasks, so 'just' have to put the actual functionality in.

Comment: Right - it takes an array of ids and runs the specified API command on each one which is often what you want but you will need something different if you want to operate on them together.